# Firebird 1.5 : Group by maximum value

Tags: sql, firebird

I got the following SQL

```
SELECT GEP.KOD, GEP.IRSZ, GEP.VAROS, GEP.UTCA, GEP.UGYINT, GEP.EMELET, CIKK.NEV,  
GEPELEM.SZAMLALO FROM GEP LEFT JOIN CIKK ON GEP.CIKK = CIKK.KOD LEFT JOIN GEPELEM ON 
GEPELEM.KOD = GEP.KOD WHERE CEG = 27013
GROUP BY GEPELEM.SZAMLALO, GEP.KOD, GEP.IRSZ, GEP.VAROS, GEP.UTCA, GEP.UGYINT, GEP.EMELET, CIKK.NEV
```

And i would like to group by GEPELEM.SZAMLALO using its  maximum value available...
If i remove the GRoup by statements and only the GEP.ELEM.SZAMLALO remains, it gives an error

```
[Error Code: 335544569, SQL State: 42000]  GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)
```

If i use max() function in the SELECT cause it does nothing. the SQL runs, but the results doesn't change
if i use max() in the group by cause and in the select:

```
[Error Code: 335544569, SQL State: 42000]  GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 11
max
```

Same error if i use it only in the Group by cause..

This is firebird 1.5.6 (got no choice to upgrade), and i come from MySQL background.

Comment: "i would like to group by GEPELEM.SZAMLALO using its maximum value available".  I don't understand what you want to do.  Try editing the question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the where clause in your JOIN condition instead of where clause, Assuming CEG is in GEPELEM table, try the following.....

```
SELECT GEP.KOD
     , GEP.IRSZ
     , GEP.VAROS
     , GEP.UTCA
     , GEP.UGYINT
     , GEP.EMELET
     , CIKK.NEV
     , MAX(GEPELEM.SZAMLALO) 
FROM GEP 
LEFT JOIN CIKK     ON GEP.CIKK    = CIKK.KOD AND  GEP.CEG = 27013
LEFT JOIN GEPELEM  ON GEPELEM.KOD = GEP.KOD   
GROUP BY GEP.KOD
     , GEP.IRSZ
     , GEP.VAROS
     , GEP.UTCA
     , GEP.UGYINT
     , GEP.EMELET
     , CIKK.NEV
```

Comment: CEG is in the GEP table, but it worked, but i don't understand why it worked... could you please explain it?

Comment: When you using an outer join and filtering out some rows in where condition on a column that only exists in one table, it will be null for the other table so it basically converts your outer join into inner join, Also you wanted Max of a column and then you tried to add that column into your Group by too, If you want Max/Min/Avg of a column you would group by all the columns in your select query except the ones you have used in any of the aggregate functions Min/Max/Avg/Sum/Count .....

Comment: @M.Ali I don't think moving `CEG` to the join condition is correct here (now all rows of `GEP` will be returned instead of only those with `CEG = 27013`). The addition of the `MAX` is probably all that was necessary.

Comment: @M.Ali thank you! and yes i added max and removed it from the group by  clause made it work! and thanks to your explanation now i know why as well!